# Как реализовать поиск совпадений по массиву?

Tags: javascript, jquery

например есть массив : `mass["one", "two" ]`, как сделать чтоб например при вводе первой буквы слова или нескольких букв выводились совпадения с массива ?

Например когда пользователь ввел o выводилось `["one", "two" ]`, а при вводе выводилось "on"  `["one"]`

Пытаюсь переделать вот такой скрипт но работать с массивом а не с объектом

```js
function search(s, arr) {
  var matches = [];

  for (var i = arr.length; i--;) {
    for (key in arr[i]) {
      if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(key) && arr[i][key].indexOf(s) > -1)
        matches.push(arr[i][key]);
    }
  }
  return matches;
};

var itemsi = ["itemsi", "iteret"];

search("i", itemsi);

console.log(search("i", itemsi));
```

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста, что вы пытались сделать, что вызвало затруднения

Comment: Добавил код который я хочу переделать под работу с массивом , но вместо того чтоб выдавать слово он выдает одну букву

Comment: Показали бы этот код который выдает одну букву. Это надо постараться что бы он букву вывел. А то что вы привели в этом вопросе вам уже дали в ответе на другой вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у массивов есть отличный метод [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) который делает как раз, то что вы хотите

```
function search(s, arr){
    var resulr = arr.filter(function(el){
        return el.indexOf(s) > -1;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function search(s, arr) {
  var matches = [];

  arr.forEach(function(elem){
    if (elem.indexOf(s) != -1) matches.push(elem);
  });

  return matches;
};

var itemsi = ["itemsi", "item"];

search("i", itemsi);

console.log(search("i", itemsi));
```

Answer (score -1):

Самый простой для понимания метод

```
let arr = [1, 1, 4, 5, 7, 7, 8, 1, 3, 4, 1];
let newArr = [];

function findeTwins() {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let temp = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            (arr[j] == arr[0])? temp.push(arr[j]) : temp = temp
        }
        (temp.length > 1) ? newArr.push(temp) : newArr = newArr
        arr = arr.filter((el) => {
            return el != arr[0]
        })
    }
}
```